# How do I display some of the properties from my objects which are saved in an array?

Tags: html, nativescript

I am working with app development, and I'm using firebase store as my database.
I'm getting some data from firebase store with I want to to display in the `component.html`.

I have the data as objects in an array, so I want to to display some of properties for each object in the array.

This is my code, which is not working as I want it to.

This is from ts component:

```
export class ClassComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = "students";
  Usersarray: User[] = [];

  constructor(private service: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.service.GetUsers().then(usersInClass => {

      this.Usersarray = usersInClass;
      console.log("from class component", this.Usersarray);

    })

  }
}
```

And this is from the html component:

```
<ScrollView>

    <StackLayout class="body">
        <ListView height="450" [items]="Usersarray">
            <ng-template let-item="item">
                <Label [text]="item.firstName"></Label>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: do you have a usersInClass example and preferably a snippet of your User Model

Comment: I got the problem, the problem was my fuction,

Comment: Put now I have another problem,  I want to display first name lastname and phone like table where first name, lastname and phone is like menu or  headline and under there will Will be. People mentioned for me to use grid put it seems differcult for me

Comment: you can use `GridLayout` inside <ng-template let-item="item">

Comment: thank you but how do i do it?

Comment: If you are not familiar with {N} layouts, you must try https://www.nslayouts.com/ which has interactive tutorial to teach you how / when you should use each layout. Refer the [ListView](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/listview) docs for more options in ListView. Also you don't have to wrap `ListView` with a `ScrollView` / `StackLayout`.

Comment: ok i will try, thank you very much